# Why is this switch statement not running?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a translator app in Android Studio using Microsoft Translator API, but for some reason, the switch statement that decides which language to translate some text into is not running.
My code is:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      final View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog, null);
      AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

      alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
      final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.LanguagePicker);
      final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Text.this,
                        R.array.language, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

      spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

      alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
      /*The setPositiveButton determines which language I want it translated to.*/
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                               //this is the main line

                               text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                               spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                               String r = textInput.getText().toString();
                               allTheTranslatedText = getTranslatedText(r);
                               Log.e("Checkpoint", "Program started to execute getTranslatedText()");
                                            textOutput.setText(allTheTranslatedText);

                             }
                           })

                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               dialog.cancel();
                             }
                            });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();


      }
    });

    }

/* getTranslatedText() outputs text */
public String getTranslatedText (String text1){
  Translate.setClientId("CLIENT ID");
  Translate.setClientSecret("CLIENT SECRET");
  String translatedText = "";
  Log.e("Checkpoint", "getTranslatedText() was called");
  try {
    switch (text) {
      case "English":
        translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.ENGLISH); // location of Unhandled exception
        outputLanguageLabel.setText("English");
        Log.e("Checkpoint", "The program should work perfectly if this appears.");

      case "French":
        translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.FRENCH);
        outputLanguageLabel.setText("French");
        // location of Unhandled exception
      case "Spanish":
        translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.SPANISH);
        outputLanguageLabel.setText("Spanish");
// location of Unhandled exception
      case "German":
        translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.GERMAN);
        outputLanguageLabel.setText("German");
// location of Unhandled exception
      case "Italian":
        translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.ITALIAN);
        outputLanguageLabel.setText("Italian");
// location of Unhandled exception
      case "Russian":
        translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.RUSSIAN);
        outputLanguageLabel.setText("Russian");
// location of Unhandled exception
      case "Mandarin":
        translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.CHINESE_TRADITIONAL);
        outputLanguageLabel.setText("Mandarin");
// location of Unhandled exception
      case "Korean":
        translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.KOREAN);
        outputLanguageLabel.setText("Korean");
// location of Unhandled exception
      case "Japanese":
        translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.JAPANESE);
        outputLanguageLabel.setText("Japanese");

// location of Unhandled exception
      default:
        Log.e("Checkpoint", "Program didn't recognize text.");
    }

  } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return translatedText;
}

}
```

I used logcat statements to determine which code is running and which code isn't, but when I selected English as the language I want my text to be translated to, logcat submitted this:

```
Checkpoint: Program started to execute getTranslatedText()
Checkpoint: getTranslatedText() was called
```

instead of what I thought it would've done:

```
Checkpoint: Program started to execute getTranslatedText()
Checkpoint: getTranslatedText() was called
Checkpoint: The program should work perfectly if this appears
```

This means the switch statement was not running, because the 3rd line would have been on logcat. Can someone please explain why?

**UPDATE:** there is also another error:

```
ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Comment: No. The variable "text" is supposed to be the Spinner's selected language, and text1 is supposed to be the text that is about to be translated.

Comment: you forget to add `break;`

Comment: Um... where do I put break?

Comment: Try logging the text inside the method.

Comment: add `break;` after every case

Comment: Why don't you log what `text` actually is right before the `switch`, and see if it's what you expect. And consider using more meaningful variable names.

Comment: It's English, so the switch statement should work perfectly.

Comment: `// location of Unhandled exception` - Well, that's kind of important. You should've mentioned that in your problem statement, instead of sticking in a code comment. Of course the log print there isn't going to execute if an Exception is thrown before it's reached.

Comment: Did you check what String r = textInput.getText().toString(); prints?

Comment: @Mike M. Actually, there isn't an Exception. That was just a comment I left behind while trying to debug it previously.

Comment: Does `outputLanguageLabel`'s text get set correctly? What does `text.equals("English")` return if you log that right before the `switch`? Are you absolutely certain that an Exception is not being thrown there? Does a stack trace print in that `catch`?

Comment: @Srijith It is the text I entered.

Comment: You should make a new question. But the error could be related with selecting the spinner. Please read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: If this question is resolved, as evidenced by the accepted answer, please don't change the question by editing to add further errors. The `ViewRootImpl` log is likely unrelated anyway.

Comment: I agree with @MikeM., you can unaccept my answer if the question isn't solved yet.

Comment: Btw, if you want to do something when spinner item is selected you need to use `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(...));`

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add [SOLVED] to the title, or the answer in the question. The accepted answer is enough to show that the question is done. If you like, you can add your own answer with the details of the resolution. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-cant-i-mark-my-title-as-solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're forget to add break in your switch statement:

```
switch (text) {
  case "English":
    translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.ENGLISH); // location of Unhandled exception
    outputLanguageLabel.setText("English");
    Log.e("Checkpoint", "The program should work perfectly if this appears.");

    // Need to add break; after case
    break;

    ...

  default:
    Log.e("Checkpoint", "Program didn't recognize text.");
}
```

For each `case`, you need to add break. If you're not, all case will go to the `default:`

---

**UPDATE**

It seems that you get the wrong `text` for switch case:

```
public String getTranslatedText (String text1){
        Translate.setClientId("CLIENT ID");
        Translate.setClientSecret("CLIENT SECRET");
        String translatedText = "";
        Log.e("Checkpoint", "getTranslatedText() was called");
        try {

            // Should check it first
            Log.d("TEXT", "text is = " + text);
            switch (text) {
               case "English":
               ...
               defaut:
               ...
            }
        }
        ..
      }
```

you need to check for `text` value.

Comment: The problem is that the default: log statement did not execute.

Comment: @MCoder: you're forget to give the `text` for switch

Comment: For some reason, it still didn't log the 3rd message.

Comment: Maybe I missing something, but I didn't found code that log `Checkpoint: The program should work perfectly if this appears`. Could you point me where the line?

Comment: In the "case: English", there is a log statement that says "Checkpoint", and "The program should work perfectly if this appears"

Comment: I'ts strange. have you select "Error" instead of "Verbose" in logcat spinner to check it?

Comment: This is just so that I can don't have to go through as much logcat statements to find these statements.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a  mistake in the switch expression, because you wrote text instead of text1 as well as you forgot the break statement.

```
public String getTranslatedText (String **text1**){
        Translate.setClientId("CLIENT ID");
        Translate.setClientSecret("CLIENT SECRET");
        String translatedText = "";
        Log.e("Checkpoint", "getTranslatedText() was called");
        try {
            switch (**text1**) {
                case "English":
                    translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.ENGLISH); // location of Unhandled exception
                    outputLanguageLabel.setText("English");
                    Log.e("Checkpoint", "The program should work perfectly if this appears.");
                        break;

                case "French":
                    translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.FRENCH);
                    outputLanguageLabel.setText("French");
                      break;
                    // location of Unhandled exception
                case "Spanish":
                    translatedText = Translate.execute(text1, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.SPANISH);
                    outputLanguageLabel.setText("Spanish");
                        break;
                           .......
```

Comment: Please try to read through the comments and other answers before you post an answer of your own.

Comment: text and text1 are meant to hold different values.